# doble ciclo for

Tags: python-3.7

Es posible hacer un for en python con dos variables que se recorran a la vez pero por distintos lados en una misma lista

Esto seria un ejemplo de lo que llevo:

```
mi_lista = [3, 2, 9, 15, 11, 8 ]
def f(lista): izquierda = [] centro = [] derecha = [] pivote = lista[0] 
for i in range(0, len(lista)): 
 if lista[i] < pivote: izquierda.append(lista[i])
 elif lista[i] == pivote: centro.append(lista[i]) 
 elif lista[i] > pivote: derecha.append(lista[i]) pivote1 = izquierda[0] 
return izquierda+centro+derecha f(mi_lista)
```

La idea del problema es solucionar el código *Quicksort*.

La idea es tomar una lista arbitraria (`lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`) y recorrer la lista de izquierda a derecha con un `for i in range(0,len(lista))` y de derecha a izquierda con otro `for`.

Cuando se encuentren los dos elementos, se elija un pivote, de esta forma creo ciertas condiciones y se me crean unas sub-listas. Pero quiero iterar esto muchas veces, con tal de que la lista se me empiece a ordenar.

No sé si utilizar una función, o otro `for` y después otro `for` sin identar, o un `while`, con tal de que la lista se ordene.

Comment: Creo que entendí tu pregunta, pero ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que esperas y que cosas intentaste?

Comment: mi_lista = [3, 2, 9, 15, 11, 8 ]

def f(lista):
    izquierda = []
    centro = []
    derecha = []
    pivote = lista[0]
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        if lista[i] < pivote:
            izquierda.append(lista[i])
        elif lista[i] == pivote:
            centro.append(lista[i])
        elif lista[i] > pivote:
            derecha.append(lista[i])
            pivote1 = izquierda[0]
                
    return izquierda+centro+derecha


f(mi_lista)

Comment: Hasta el momento este es el código montado en python por ejemplo

Comment: SI tengo una lista l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] quiero hacer un for que me recorra la lista de izquierda a derecha y otro for que me recorra la lista de derecha a izquierda, pero que actúen simultáneamente todo esto es para encontrar una solución al algoritmo Quicksort , es para ahorrarme la definición de la función, me parece más sencillo poner a correr los dos for, pero no se como.

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y colocar todo eso ahí para cumplir con las normas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder responder a tu pregunta.

Comment: La idea del problema es solucionar el código Quicksort, la idea es tomar una lista arbitraria digamos lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ahora quiero recorrer la lista de izquierda a derecha con un for i in range(0,len(lista)) y la lista de derecha a izquierda con otro for. Cuando se encuentren los dos elementos se me elija un pivote, de esta forma creo ciertas condiciones y se me crean unas sub-listas pero quiero iterar esto muchas veces, con tal de que la lista se me empiece a ordenar. No se si utilizar una función, o otro for y después otro for sin identar, o un while, con tal de que la lista se ordene.

Comment: Lo siento, tu pregunta esta mal formada debes editarla. Por lo tanto, no puedo responderla porque iría contra las normas: [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).